# UnicodeDecodeError while using LaTeX in Python

Tags: errors, unicode

When trying to run a code containing text written for LaTeX I get an error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 1281: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'm writing text in Latvian so it contains "weird" characters like ā, ī and š. How can I solve this?

Code(I'm using library manim):

```
from manim import *


class Definition(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        ddefin = Tex(r'Šis teksts ir rakstīts Latviešu valodā.')
        self.add(ddefin)
```

Comment: There are ways to have LaTeX accept unicode characters.  But it's not clear how you're going from Python to TeX (manim appears to be for videos).  Where does the TeX command come from?  How do you construct your TeX file's preamble?

Comment: I think this is a purely python question, the string you show is correctly encoded utf-8 here but check it is correct in the original source as cut and paste to the site can reencode the text. The only byte hex a1 in the string is from `š`  which is the two UTF-8 bytes C5 A1

Comment: When I try your code in the online notebook on https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/behackl/725d956ec80969226b7bf9b4aef40b78/HEAD?filepath=basic%20example%20scenes.ipynb (linked from https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/) then I don't get the error and the text is rendered with the correct characters. So it is an issue with your local setup. Maybe you use an old Python version?